# Publishing dissertation chapters instead of a monograph

Tags: publications, thesis, books, humanities, monograph

I am at the end of my second year of a tenure-track position (my institution uses calendar years instead of academic ones) with a heavy load of service. This academic year I was assigned to work on six committees.

I defended my dissertation in 2013. I intended to turn the dissertation into a book but after three years applying to jobs while having temporary positions I barely could find the time to work on it. My mentor suggested to publish the dissertation chapters as journal articles since the book is not required for tenure and it has been the norm in the department.

I have mixed feelings about this but I know that with the teaching and service load it would be extremely hard to work on the book; especially since I will have to translate it – my specialization is Spanish literature and my thesis is in Spanish.

Should I publish the dissertation as articles and then think of a new project for a future book publication?

Answer (score 2):

> Would you publish the dissertation as articles and then think of a new project for a future book publication?

Yes, I would. Your mentor is right.